# Partial insulation of suspended timber floor possible?

Tags: insulation, floor

We live in a Victorian terraced house and will be putting tiling down in the hallway. I’d like to know whether at the same time we should also do something to improve the insulation of the floor.

Would we need to insulate the whole floor at once, or can we do the Hall now and the adjacent living room later?

Comment: Is there an unheated basement below the floor? What is the current finished floor? By connecting the insulation installation to the installation of tile, it seems you are considering putting insulation on top of the existing floor and under the proposed tile floor. Won't this result in a discontinuity where the tile ends? Have other owners of similar properties in Cambridge UK used tile? Is the floor rigid enough to install tile? You might want to use a "decoupling" membrane to reduce the potential for cracking.

Comment: No basement. There’s some new wood over the timbers in the hall and carpet in the living room. I’d be looking to insulate under the timbers as they would need to be lifted and reseated as part of the tiling (apparently). The tiler is already proposing to install the sort of decoupling membrane you mention. I’m considering insulation at the same time as tiling as retrospectively doing it would be much harder, post-tiling. Does any of that make sense? Thanks Jim!

Comment: Is the current finish floor hardwood planks (e.g., oak)? If so, you would be covering up an expensive and attractive floor. Normally it is OK for a hall to be somewhat colder than sitting rooms. I am Scottish and shrink from doing things that could be considered unnecessary.

Comment: Lifting timbers and re-seating them as part of tiling is not something I have ever heard of, but I am not familiar with construction practices in the UK. When was this set of row houses constructed?

Comment: The tiles would replace an inexpensive wooden finish that’s currently above the original timbers. The house was built in the late 1800s.

Comment: So are you going to leave in place or remove the 'inexpensive wooden finish' flooring? Is it common when renovating these Victorian terraced houses to insulate on top of the sub-floor, i.e, between the new finished floor  and the sub-floor? Is the space under the floor not accessible? Is the floor cold right now or do you think that tile would be colder than what you have right now and might be so cold as to be uncomfortable?

Comment: The current finish would be removed. I don’t know if it’s common to insulate above the timbers, but I believe there’s an opportunity to insulate below when the timbers are reseated. It is currently cold, although not too cold. I imagine tiles would be cooler.